# LUKS2 - RAID0 - NVME : alignment issue

Tags: software-raid, luks, nvme, device-mapper

I have trouble while in top of this stack bellow:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/raid0luks2
/dev/mapper/raid0luks2 alignement is offset by 147456 bytes
This may result in very poor performance (re-) partitioning is suggested.
I have the same pb with mkfs.xfs
```

I am using following stack :

> ```
> LUKS2  => created with cryptsetup -v luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/md127 --cipher aes-gcm-random --integrity aeae  
> software RAID 0 => created with mdadm chunk=32  
> 3 Disks NVME => partition with gdisk (fist sector : 2048)
> ```

I got this information with lsblk -t for each 3 disks, i got the same information.

```
nvmeXn1
-> NvmeXn1p1       ALIGN = 0
-> md127           ALIGN = 0
-> raid0luks2_dif  ALIGN = 147456
-> raid0luks2      ALIGN = 147456
```

1. How can I solve my alignment issue?
2. Is it normal to have low
   performances while writing with dd. I was using LUKS previously and
   I got only one dev mapper with good performances. Now I got 2. Does it have a big impact on performances?

Kind regards.